# How do I properly dereference a buffer?

Tags: java

I am having some memory problems with a project of mine. After a bit of tracing memory on several positions in my program, I retraced the problem to this line:

```
(FloatBuffer)lightBuffer.asFloatBuffer().put(lightAmbient).flip()
```

I am using the resultant buffer in a function straight away, but it seems that that float buffer is not emptied after it has been used. 
So how do I properly empty/dereference a buffer in java?

ps: I tried the clear() method, but according to the java documentation that only resets the buffer; it does not remove the data from it.

Comment: Why isn't clear sufficient? You could resuse the buffer afterwards as if the data was released. Alternatively you could make the buffer elligible for garbage collection and create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `lightBuffer` is a ByteBuffer (it seems no other class has a method `asFloatBuffer`), your FloatBuffer object is only a wrapper around the same underlying `byte[]` or native memory.

This FloatBuffer object does not eat any more memory (but uses the same memory the `lightBuffer` uses), but it could hinder the garbage collection of the ByteBuffer - but it seems you are reusing this one, don't you?

So there seems to be no problem so far (apart from you not knowing that there are several Buffers using the same memory).

Comment: +1 Just a note: sometimes (rarely) with direct-buffers of which many are being allocated (perhaps another issue) there is not enough GC pressure to make them "die" fast enough. There are some hacks using the "internal" methods to force a direct-buffer to release its backing sooner.

Comment: lightBuffer is a ByteBuffer, yes (sorry.. forgot to include that). I am reusing the lightBuffer too. I didn't know about them using the same memory either. Then I guess that my memory problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thing is; once I comment out this line, the memory usage of the program is constant. Once I enable it, it starts leaking memory at about 300 Kb/s. So I am completely puzzled by that fact, especially since you said that the memory is shared; it shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you stored a reference to this buffer somewhere? I don't think that you can explicitly "remove the data" from the buffer and System.gc() won't help you here.

The garbage collector should handle this automatically for you unless you are maintaining a reference to this buffer.

Comment: +1 Just a note: sometimes (rarely) with direct-buffers of which many are being allocated (perhaps another issue) there is not enough GC pressure to make them "die" fast enough because the data for direct-buffers is not managed. There are some hacks using the "internal" methods to force a direct-buffer to release its backing sooner but there is, unfortunately, no Closable/Disposable interface. Of course using such a buffer with a released backing results in nasty exceptions :-)

Comment: I am creating the buffer object, and then passing it to an openGL function. The line from above is from inside one of the parameters of that function, so I guess that shouldn't leave any reference behind, unless openGl keeps it. Which _should_ not be the case

Answer (score 0):

Er, you don't.

The NIO buffers don't waste time with such things, they overwrite data in the buffer and move the marks.

If you want to get rid of it, you have to get rid of all references to it and make it available to the GC so it can be collected.